# What is the die progression for a Champion wielding a Great Sword?

Tags: weapons, pathfinder-2e

At 1st level, [Champions gain the Deific Weapon feature](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=4), which states:

> You zealously bear your deity’s favored weapon. If it’s uncommon, you gain access to it. If it’s an unarmed attack with a d4 damage die or a simple weapon, increase the damage die by one step (d4 to d6, d6 to d8, d8 to d10, d10 to d12).

Given that a Greatsword (as well as several other weapons in the Core Rulebook) deals 1d12 as a default, does a Champion wielding a Greatsword see any benefit from this feature?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Deific Weapon Doesn't Affect Greatswords

Deific Weapon has 2 functions:

- Granting access to an Uncommon weapon
- Increasing the damage die by one step for:

  - Simple Weapons
  - Unarmed Attacks that deal 1d4 damage

A [Greatsword](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=24) is a Common Martial weapon, and thus doesn't benefit at all, with the exception of a custom campaign setting in which your GM has declared Greatswords Uncommon (in which case you're probably working with custom dieties anyway).

**The damage die remains a d12.**

### There are currently no printed d12 simple weapons

The question under your question (what happens when increasing beyond a d12 I presume) is that this is currently impossible through Deific Weapon, and I'm not aware of any way to do it through other feats or features. However, even if it were...

### You Can't Increase Beyond d12

If somehow you found a way to increase the damage die of a d12 weapon, you simply wouldn't. From the [damage rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=226):

> When an effect calls on you to increase the size of your weapon damage dice, instead of using its normal weapon damage dice, use the next larger die, as listed below (so if you were using a d4, you’d use a d6, and so on). ***If you are already using a d12, the size is already at its maximum.*** You can’t increase your weapon damage die size more than once.

Comment: Gotcha, I was missing the part whereby the die increase only applies for simply weapons. I was thinking it was just a blanket application.